# Assign a function pointer using template method?

Tags: templates, pointers, visual-c++, c++-cli

consider the Utility class below:

It will contain lots of factory methods with same signature `int function(int a, int b);`

**Utility.h**

```
class Utility
{
 public:

    template<typename T, typename A, typename B> 
    static int get_function(T% function, int% number)
    {
        function = (T) add;
        number = 10;
        return 0;
    }

    static int add (int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

this contains a template method (get_function()) to assign Function pointers from factory methods available in `Utility` class.

**Main.cpp**

```
typedef int (__stdcall *FP) (int a, int b);


ref class FPClass
{    
    public:
        static FP fp;

        static int number;

        static void apply_function()
        {
            Utility::get_function<FP, int, int>(FPClass::fp, number);
            cout <<  FPClass::fp(25, 45);
        }
};


void main()
{
    FPClass::apply_function();
}
```

What I want to achieve is, to assign the function pointer (`FPClass::fp`) by the template method (`Utility:get_function`).

But the function pointer parameter is not modified (always null) by the called function (`Utility:get_function`).
why is that?

Comment: What language do you use? Is it C++/CLI?

Comment: It is a very strange mix of managed and native code, the debugger gets too confused to display the value of "fp" correctly.  It does however work.  The (T) cast in the template is extraordinarily evil.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant.. I did not go ahead and execute, stopped in debugging phase itself :)

Comment: About the strange mix, I have to do it, as I have to use function pointers & other features from managed code side such as Garbage collection, Collections, .Net classes etc :)

Comment: @HansPassant can you add this as an answer here?